# jquery regex for non zero comma separated numbers in textbox

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using `^\d+(,\d+)*$` regEx in Jquery for comma separated numbers but his allows Number 0 as well.

i.e. if I write 0,123 or 123,0 or 465,586,0 or 857,0,546 then it will pass but for my requirement if should fail validation.

What kind changes need to be done for not allowing 0 in comma separated numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me whether `10,123` would be allowed (contains the *character* `0` but obviously the *number* is `10` here). If `10` **is** allowed, this should do it:

```
^[1-9]\d*(,[1-9]\d*)*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2o6J6234bdrjIJmH)

Otherwise:

```
^[1-9]+(,[1-9]+)*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VerHMNuu9uTIUgUa)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^[1-9]+(,\d+)*$
```

and if you want to have more than one number before comma:

```
^[1-9]\d*(,\d+)*$
```

Comment: @vaibhavshah i understand that only former 0 must be exclude

Comment: @A.Wolff my second regex will exclude former 0 and allow any other values including 0

Comment: @antyrat ya, i was answering to vaibhav's comment

Comment: 0 can be at any place. i.e.   0,123 or  123,0  not allowed

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want zeros to match the regular expression, Just replace `\d` by `[1-9]`